# Uploading HTML of bookdown and RMarkdown files on a custom website (using netlify)

Tags: r, r-markdown, netlify, bookdown

I have a custom website, which has been connected to my github repo through Netlify.

I would like to add HTML output of Rmarkdown and bookdown files in my custom website.

An example would be this:
https://clauswilke.com/dataviz/

The bookdown output is hosted on the custom website.

It'd be great if anyone could explain how this could be done. So far, my bookdown is only hosted on github.